# Deploy software with no .msi in AD

Tags: active-directory, installation

I have a small AD in which I am deploying software to domain computers through GPO (using msi installers).

What is the best method to deploy software that

- has no .msi installer,
- but has switches for silent installs

All I can think is to use startup scripts (that will do detect->install/uninstall/upgrade), but I was wondering if there are existing wheel designs in this area...

NOTE:
I'd like to avoid repackaging to .msi format (unless someone convinces me otherwise).

Some examples of software that I would like to deploy

- picasa 3
- VLC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the freeware version of [witem](http://www.witemsoft.com/)  to create .msi files with "custom actions" which run your non-msi installers.

I've used it and It works well.

Comment: +1, It's a good idea to fill in the uninstall actions as well.

Answer (score 3):

If the installation can be scripted and run silently, a startup script is probably your best choice here; all other available options need some system management software (such as Microsoft's System Center Configuration Manager).

Answer (score 1):

When you are dealing with a non-MSI (most likely an .exe) you can use other installers. [PDQ Deploy is a free installer](http://www.adminarsenal.com/pdq-deploy/main/) that allows you to push MSI, EXE, .BAT, .MSU, .MSP, .CMD, .you_get_the_point. (PDQ Deploy is made by my company).

You can also use SCCM, Tivoli, or many other products for deploying software, but these are a tad pricey (and by a tad I mean a ton).