# Is it possible to install the junipersetupclient.exe for all users instead of single, per-user?

Tags: juniper

I have lots of computers and lots of users.  They all need the junipersetupclient.exe.  Is it possible to install the client for all users, so they each get the ocx?  Or is is per-user only?

I cannot find anything online about it.

Windows 7 Pro, AD domain.

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a vendor-specific question that you should really ask them about.

Comment: The answer for a software-distribution question can certainly have a non-vendor-specific characteristic. And I don't think that "vendor-specific" is a good "off-topic" reason, in many cases. If vendor-specific were disqualifying that would include the vendors of the operating systems that we manage. We're not here to discuss theory of Turing machines; we're here to ask and answer questions about real-life systems administration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deploy software with no .msi in AD](http://serverfault.com/questions/175173/deploy-software-with-no-msi-in-ad)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Package the EXE as an MSI (you'll need to get a tool to do that; there are free and commercial ones) and Assign the MSI via GPO to the OU(s) that contain the "lots of computers".  That's the generic answer for any software distribution to Windows clients in a AD domain.